# Count only NAs across categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

| Category | Score | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | nan | 1 |
| A | 95 | 1 |
| A | nan | 2 |
| B | nan | 2 |
| B | nan | 2 |
| B | nan | 3 |
| C | 95 | 3 |
| C | nan | 3 |

I want to find the count of those IDs with *only* nan values across each category. Based on the table above, my result would look like:

| Category | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 0 |

Here's what I have so far but I'm not sure this is providing the correct numbers:

```
out = (df[df['score'].isna()]
        .groupby('category')
        .apply(lambda g: g.groupby('id')
        .filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 1)['id'].nunique())
        .to_frame('Count')
        .reset_index())
print(out)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

First you groupby `Category` and `ID` and check with `isna()` and `all()` if every value in a group is `nan`, which will return True and False. Converting True and False to integer will change the values to 1 and 0. Then groupby again, but only the `Categorys` and sum the values (sum the 1's which came from True)

```
out = (df
       .groupby(['Category', 'ID'])['Score']
       .apply(lambda x: x.isna().all().astype(int))
       .groupby('Category')
       .sum()
       .reset_index(name='count')
      )
print(out)
```

```
  Category  count
0        A      1
1        B      2
2        C      0
```